# teechart Export image with size specified

Tags: activex, teechart

I have issue with export functionality, If I am setting legend as custom position say 88% from left and also panel i am defining as 15% from right. then when i do export image as Bitmap and provide the size as 200 x 200 it exports only chart legend are exported or not shown on the chart even if they are shown they are half cutted.

Please let me know an alternate solution for the same.

Thanks
Akshay

Comment: width and height of exported image should not less than chart width and height respectively other otherwise whole image will not export.

Comment: Please add the code so we can reproduce the problem here. http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution which we did was we check whether the width of the legend is greater then half the size of the chart and if it is so we are adding the legend at the bottom of the chart instead of left.